# Connecting to azure's "MySQL in app" database through a remote console

Tags: mysql, database, bash, shell, azure

I have a web app in azure, of the MySQL in app type, it is a server with an instance of MySQL but the problem is that I can only manage the DB with PHPMyAdmin and I prefer to use the shell, so my question would be where can I verify the host, the user and the password that I must use to access from a console remotely?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this original App Service announcement](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/08/18/Announcing-MySQL-in-app-for-Web-Apps-(Windows).html) for in-app MySql in 2016:

> MySQL database cannot be accessed remotely. You can only access your
>   database content using PHPMyadmin or using MySQL utilities in KUDU
>   debug console.

And also

> The database is protected by our sandbox environment and hence cannot
>   be accessed remotely through MySQL workbench or MySQL command line
>   tools (running on remote machine).

It would appear that this limitation is still in place.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbled on this, to access the DB using PHP, use
`https://name-of-your-site.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin/index.php`

Took me a while to find it,

Answer (score -3):

You should get all these information looking in your Azure Portal, the "SQL Databases".

In the Overview menu, you'll get a **Connection strings** link with all the information you need.

Edit: and then you will be able to use this **Connection Strings** inside your application.

Comment: The question is for 'in-app' mysql db

Comment: Yes, and I answered this way. I added one more information => it is more clear?